# InflateException with TextInputLayout and AlertDialog

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to use the newest **TextInputLayout** in my **DialogFragment**.

Here's my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/testingInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/testingEditText"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/testText"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Some background info:

- The activity that launches the DialogFragment derives from **AppCompatActivity**
- The DialogFragment derives from **Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment**
- I build the DialogFragment via the **Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder**
- The DialogFragment is launched via a **SupportFragmentManager**
- I am using the latest **Support Design Library**

Here's the error (I'm using Xamarin, hence the *MonoDroid*)

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
[MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00078>
[MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:195
[MonoDroid] at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup) [0x0006d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:646
[MonoDroid] at HelloLittleApp.MyOwnDialog.OnCreateDialog (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00027] in e:\Progetti\HelloLittleApp-Android\Dialogs\MyOwnDialog.cs:22
[MonoDroid] at Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment.n_OnCreateDialog_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00013, 0x000f7>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.e260d9fd-b921-4418-a47a-496934404e0e (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x0004b>
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
[MonoDroid]     at md5a2b8d0e6e3890b714223a2b1204f749c.MyOwnDialog.n_onCreateDialog(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at md5a2b8d0e6e3890b714223a2b1204f749c.MyOwnDialog.onCreateDialog(MyOwnDialog.java:29)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:308)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
[MonoDroid] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
[MonoDroid]     ... 21 more
[MonoDroid] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 18
[MonoDroid]     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:166)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:106)
[MonoDroid]     ... 24 more
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
```

Any tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had similar error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

Trying to reproduce it for a new project I found that the problem for me was in App Theme! Try to set `android:theme` field in `application` tag of Android Manifest like this:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Comment: It worked for me too, but it also removed my ActionBar!

Comment: Oops, you also need to implement AppCompatActivity instead of Activity. Then it works fine.

Comment: My minimumSDK and targetSDK are API 22. Should I use `@style/Theme.AppCompat` or `@style/android:Theme.Material` ?

Comment: My style is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` however in `values-c21` styles file i found resource tag started like this `<resources>>` instead of `<resources>` could that be the reason for this error `Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/design_password_eye.xml from drawable resource ID `

Answer (score 18):

This happened to me as well, and I came up with a solution inspired by [AHTOH's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31000599/763080). It requires simply changing the Theme of the TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/testingInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/testingEditText"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/testText"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You will need to add the appCompat library if you have not already:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

- extend your activity from AppCompatActivity
- extend your (dialog)fragment from android.support.v4.app.Fragment.
- use latest version of design library.
- Instead of using EditText, use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText. For example:

  ```
      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      app:errorEnabled="true">

                      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:hint="First Name"
                          android:inputType="textPersonName"
                          android:singleLine="true" />

      </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
  ```

Also, if you didn't do so already: 
Set AppCompat theme in your manifest application tag:

```
<application
   ...
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

And inherit AppCompat at your styles.xml as root for your activity styles etc.:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText`?

Answer (score 3):

With recent announcement in Google I/O 2018, and refractor of `com.android.` to `androidx.` all support libraries got affected too.

So, you may have to change your dependencies to `com.google.android.material:material:<Major.Version.Number><-beta|alpha Version>`
as of 06th of July 2018, I am using
`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01`

And above the class `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` and `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` has been changed to 
`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` and `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`

Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor) link  to get a better idea of what all support libraries got refractored.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the Theme is set properly in the manifest, this might happen depending on the *Context* you are inflating from. You can fix this by using a *ContextWrapper* with your AppTheme (or another one) when initialising the *LayouInflater*:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), R.style.AppTheme));
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` error too. It turned out to be caused by my  `proguard/gradle config` . I was using the `shrinkResources` directive in my **release build config**.

After i removed the `shrinkResources` directive from my release build config everything started working again.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error but it ended up being a completely different context. I didn't see my exact issue outlined elsewhere so posting an answer here hoping it will save others time. In my case, this exception was thrown:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

However, it was related to the implementation for the FileProvider camera permissions. That implementation involved adding an xml file under Resources/xml.

Having anything in the Resources/xml folder would throw the exception. Both FileProvider and TextInputLayout worked independently but not when used in the same project.

The result that worked for me was to move all xml files from Resource/xml to Resources/layout and reference them with @layout/my_reference_here.

This seems like a bug in Visual Studio/Xamarin, but at least I was able to move forward. I hope this helps another avoid burning a couple of days of time hunting it down.